# How to check if div has a specific value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I want to know how I can let the JavaScript react when the div has a certain value.

```
<div id="background">
<div id="value">1</div>
</div>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("value");
if (text = "0") {
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>
```

If the value div has 0, I want the background color to be red of the div called background. If the value div has a other value, it should do nothing. This is what I've come up to. But it don't work. Even if I put another value in the value div, the red background still shows. Except when I emptied the value div, then ofcourse you will see nothing.

Comment: You need to use double equals "==" to perform a comparison.  If you use a single then you are actually setting the value.

Comment: Ugh, I knew something wasn't right about the equal.. Thank you. Just started JavaScript you could say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison operators in JavaScript are `==` and `===`, not `=` (that one is always *assignment*). So:

```
if (text == "0") {
```

or

```
if (text === "0") {
```

You're also not getting the text correctly:

```
var text = document.getElementById("value");
```

That gives you the *element*, not its contents. For contents, use `innerHTML`.

```
var text = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
// Here -----------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just started JavaScript you could say.

Answer (score 6):

```
var text = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
if (text == "0") {
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="background">
<div id="value">1</div>
</div>
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("value").innerHTML;
if (text == "0") {
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u1peb5j7/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use jquery:

```
if($("#value").html() == "0") {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "red");
}
```